# Расположение языков в меню сайта вертикально

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть вот такое простенькое меню. Как можно объединить 2 языка в одну группу, чтобы в ней они были вертикально, но эта группа была горизонталью к 2 другим ссылкам

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  line-height: 120px;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 120px;
}

.logo a {
  color: #9fc240;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #9fc240;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.show-menu-btn,
.hide-menu-btn {
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.show-menu-btn {
  float: right;
  color: #9fc240;
}

.show-menu-btn i {
  line-height: 120px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

#chk {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1111;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .show-menu-btn,
  .hide-menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #333;
    right: -100%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 80px 0;
    line-height: normal;
    transition: 0.7s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .menu a {
    display: block;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .hide-menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
  }
  #chk:checked~.menu {
    right: 0;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">
<div class="header">
  <div class='logo'>
    <a href="">
    ЛОГО
  </a>
  </div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chk" color="red">
  <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>

  <ul class="menu">
    <a href="/">Ссылка 1 </a>
    <a href="/logist/">Ссылка 2</a>
    <a href="/ru/"> ru  </a>
    <a href="/en/"> en  </a>
    <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
      </label>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Хочу получить примерно такой результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обернуть все дочерние тэги `<ui>` тегами `<li><a>...</li>`

Comment: @AlexanderChernin я пробовал. Но они съезжали вниз под ссылки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так (я выкинул лишнее и не принципиальное)?

```css
.menu {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
}

.menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu li {
  list-style: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px red inset;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu a {
  color: #9fc240;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">


  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/">Ссылка 1 </a></li>
    <li><a href="/logist/">Ссылка 2</a></li>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/ru/"> ru  </a></li>
      <li><a href="/en/"> en  </a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  color: #fff;
}

.logo a {
  color: #9fc240;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu a {
  color: #9fc240;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.langs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.langs a + a {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.show-menu-btn,
.hide-menu-btn {
  display: none;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: color 0.4s;
}

.show-menu-btn {
  color: #9fc240;
}

.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
  color: #3498db;
}

#chk {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:800px) {
  .show-menu-btn,
  .hide-menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 80px 0;
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.7s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .menu a {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  
  .langs {
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  
  .langs a + a {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  .hide-menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 40px;
  }
  
  #chk:checked + .menu {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css">

<div class="header">
  <div class='logo'>
    <a href="#">ЛОГО</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu-wrapper">
    <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </label>
    
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    
    <div class="menu">
      <a href="/">Ссылка 1</a>
      <a href="/logist/">Ссылка 2</a>
      
      <div class="langs">
        <a href="/ru/">ru</a>
        <a href="/en/">en</a>
      </div>
      
      <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```